# ReGex: Get multiple Matches out of repeating sequence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a multiline string in python using regex. My regex experience is limited.

The string has a structure like this:

```
asdf
foo 1
bar
barfoo
bar
foo 2
baz 
baz 
...
foo 20 
bat
bat
```

I'm looking for an expression that will find multiple matches, as currently I only find everything or nothing. So the output should be something like:

```
["foo 1\nbarbarfoobar","foo 2 \nbaz\nbaz\n...",...]
```

As I understand it, I should look for a `foo \d+` followed by some random stuff... `((\n|.*)?)*`

```
foo \d+((\n|.*)?)*
```

I've researched about negative lookaheads, but inserting one did not help me.

```
foo \d+((\n|.*)?)*(?!foo)
```

I guess this could be solved by using only the built-in `String` methods, but later on I'll have to do things like this alot, so I'm looking for a "simple" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([\s\S]+?(?=(?:\nfoo \d+|$)))
```

You can try this with `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/5

Comment: This only works when there is no trailing Bulk data like `asdf`.

Comment: To exclude those:
`(foo \d+[\s\S]+?(?=(?:\nfoo \d+|$)))`